# The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace 'Sitecore.XConnect.Client'

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I'm trying to implement XConnect in a Sitecore context and using the code snippet

`using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
 {   }`

Here,

> Error    CS0234    The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not
>   exist in the namespace 'Sitecore.XConnect.Client' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)

I have added Sitecore.xConnect and Sitecore.xConnect.Client into the references as well as in the name space. But Still the issue is not resolved and getting this error. I have added these dll's through nuget package manager.
Any idea on this issue or I'm missing something??

Refering this [Sitecore doc website](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/xconnect-client-api-overview/get-client-in-sitecore.html)

Comment: Can you add reference to Sitecore.Configuration namespace ?

Comment: I Couldn't find sitecore.configuration dll from nuget or from bin folder. what is the exact name of the dll. Sitecore.configuration is present in sitecore.kernel dll. After adding that also same error is showing

Comment: Sitecore.Configuration is in Sitecore.Kernel.dll, please try to add reference to using System.Configuration;

Comment: Here I have added - Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration dll which has removed the name space error.. Can I use this ..?

Comment: yes..that's the correct dll

Comment: I have added below 3 dll
1) Sitecore.XConnect.dll
2) Sitecore.XConnect.Client.dll
3) Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.dll
from my sitecore instance is that fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After adding Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration dll  from nuget package has resolved my issue which helps in creating Xconnect client object in sitecore context.

> Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration dll